# How to set the div go behind the pop up window

Tags: html, css, popup, sharepoint-online

Pop-up window comes with the default search bar in SPO tenant site. So I don't have access to modify any CSS in the search field. I want to set the div in behind when the window pops up.

Comment: Do you have any code, please? This would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: Screenshot of the webpage and the pop-up would  also  be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Explain what you exactly mean. If you want some element in your html appear behind some other element in a single page then you need to use z-index css property. Put an integer as the value of z-index property. The first html element (the one that is behind the other)  should have value less than the one that is on the front. give both of the elements z-index.